# OpenCart 3, Multistore with different Admin panel and Database (Template folder from main domain)

Tags: php, twig, opencart, multistore

I am looking for a solution with Multistore or something like that.
The task is to have more than 5 sites with the same path to the template, but with different products / product prices, addresses and admin panel for orders

What can be done to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

In config.php

define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');

Controls where the templates are and you should be able to load the templates from a single directory outside the document root.

You could also make  "view/theme" a symbolic link to a common shared directory outside of the webroot.

This may become a nightmare to manage over the long term unless you keep all the separate systems identical and never install any modules.